# How to make multiple http requests in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to chain a promise with Angular $resource.

I have the following factory:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Product', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/api/product/:name',
        { name: '@name' },
        { 'getSub': {
                url: '/api/product/getSub/:name',
                method: 'GET'}
         }
    );
}]);
```

I make multiple queries using my Product factory as such:

```
Product.query({'name': name}, function(product) {
     Product.getSub({'name': product.name}, function(subItem) {
         Product.getSub({'name':subItem.name}, function(childItem) {
             //do stuff with child item
         })
     })
})
```

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like nesting all these calls is not a best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the promises together!

```
Product.query({'name': name}).$promise
.then(function(product){
  return Product.getSub({'name': product.name}).$promise;
})
.then(function(subItem){
  return Product.getSub({'name': subItem.name}).$promise;
})
.then(function(item){
  // etc
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use waterfall of [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) or implement it yourself.
here's sample code for your case.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        Product.query({'name': name}, function(product) {
            callback(null, product);
        })
    },
    function(product, callback) {
        Product.getSub({'name': product.name}, function(subItem) {
            callback(null, product, subItem);
        })
    },
    function(product, subItem, callback) {
        Product.getSub({'name':subItem.name}, function(childItem) {
            var result = {};
            result.childItem = childItem;
            result.subItem = subItem;
            result.product = product;

            callback(null, result);
        })
    }
], function (err, result) {
    //do stuff with result
});
```

Comment: hm...I am not looking adding more library to my app as it already has a lot. Thanks though +1

Answer (score 0):

A useful solution maybe use $q library

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

You can use the method $q.all() to send a lot of request and manage only one callback then() or make $q.defer() and resolve por reject your oun promises.

I currently answer this question from a mobile device and i can't make an example. Sorry about that. 
 If when I get home that mistake trains still try to help

Answer (score 0):

If you want the requests to be done one after another (like you have in your example) you could do a recursive function like this:

in this example i want to upload a couple of images (calling a http route):

```
$scope.uploadImageLayout = function (currentIndex, numberOfItems) {
        if (currentIndex === numberOfItems) {
            // in here you could do some last code after everything is done
        } else {
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'localhost:3000/ficheiros',
                file: $scope.imagesToUpload[$scope.auxIndex].file
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if ($scope.auxIndex < numberOfItems) {
                    $scope.uploadImageLayout(currentIndex + 1, numberOfItems);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

and the first time you call just do this:

```
$scope.uploadImageLayout(0, $scope.imagesToUpload.length);
```

in you case its the same but instead of the Upload.upload request you should have your request and catch the callback function(s).